# Is there a way to convert tkinter "drawing" to a bytearray?

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, tkinter, draw

**Goal** in the end **is to have a board** (example dimensions: width = 200, height = 20), whereas each "width/height" unit is a pixel **on the tkinter GUI**. When the pixel is being pressed it stays "marked", enabling me **to draw pictures** on this board. Important is that I can get the information which "Pixels" are **marked/not marked** (preferably **in a byte array**, e.g. 11010100, where as 1 is "clicked" and 0 "not clicked").

*The term "pixels" might be confusing in this context, I didn't know how to better describe it. I got an analogy (which is a bit ridiculous, but here: The "magnetic drawing boards for children" are; [click here for a google image](https://i0.wp.com/ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HLB1TQDRajDuK1Rjy1zjq6zraFXaD/Colorful-font-b-Magnetic-b-font-font-b-Drawing-b-font-font-b-Board-b-font.jpg?crop=5,2,900,500&quality=2886); The board is in this case my tkinter GUI where I can draw and in the end, upon "saving" / being finished, I get the marked pixels in a bytearray, preferably from left to right, where each column is read from up to down)*

**I tried** the Canvas (which obviously) isn't working; as well as making each "pixel" a button (due to the broad variety of settings it's a perfect fit), though tkinter buttons, especially 100+ tend to load quite a while.

//EDIT:
[image]
*self drawn*; The drawing board should alike - I need the information which "pixels" have been marked, so I can put them in an array (and maybe re-construct it later, and so forth)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create a grid of rectangles on a canvas. You can then create a drawing by setting the color of each individual rectangle. To get the bytearray you can iterate over the rectangles to get their color.

Here's a quick and dirty example. You can paint by clicking and dragging. When you click the "Print Data" button it will print a list of strings with a "1" wherever a square is black.

[image: screenshot]

This is the output of the button:

```
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000001000001000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00001000000000001000
00000100000000010000
00000011111111100000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class DrawableGrid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height, size=5):
        super().__init__(parent, bd=1, relief="sunken")
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.size = size
        canvas_width = width*size
        canvas_height = height*size
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

        for row in range(self.height):
            for column in range(self.width):
                x0, y0 = (column * size), (row*size)
                x1, y1 = (x0 + size), (y0 + size)
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1,
                                             fill="white", outline="gray",
                                             tags=(self._tag(row, column),"cell" ))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("cell", "<B1-Motion>", self.paint)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("cell", "<1>", self.paint)

    def _tag(self, row, column):
        """Return the tag for a given row and column"""
        tag = f"{row},{column}"
        return tag

    def get_pixels(self):
        row = ""
        for row in range(self.height):
            output = ""
            for column in range(self.width):
                color = self.canvas.itemcget(self._tag(row, column), "fill")
                value = "1" if color == "black" else "0"
                output += value
            print(output)

    def paint(self, event):
        cell = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(cell, fill="black")


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = DrawableGrid(root, width=20, height=15, size=10)
b = tk.Button(root, text="Print Data", command=canvas.get_pixels)
b.pack(side="top")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```